# Elasticsearch построить запрос аналогичный SQL (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, elasticsearch

Есть запрос:

SELECT * FROM `shop_items` WHERE (`shop_category` IS NULL) AND (`title` NOT LIKE '%Ночник%') AND ((`title` LIKE '%мышь%') OR (`title` LIKE '%клавиат%')) AND (`description` LIKE '%беспровод%') ORDER BY `is_top`

Ищу по 3 полям:
shop_category, 
title,
description

Как построить аналогичный запрос на Elasticsearch?

Comment: Странный запрос и работать будет довольно долго. У вас в архитектуре БД не используются справочники типов?

Answer (score 1):

Если значения полей title и description в индексе разбиты на правильные токены, то можно использовать [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html). И запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
{
  "sort" : {
    "is_top" : {"order" : "asc"}
  },
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        { "term" : { "description" : "беспровод" } },
        {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : [
              { "term" : { "title" : "мышь" } },
              { "term" : { "title" : "клавиат" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        { "exists" : { "field" : "shop_category" } },
        { "term" : { "title" : "Ночник" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

В противном случае нужно использовать [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-regexp-query.html).

Нельзя однозначно составить аналог сложного SQL запроса на Query DSL. Очень разные парадигмы. Elasticsearch не предназначен для LIKE-запросов.